# Which one is the real Bubble Sort, and which one is better?

Tags: c++, algorithm, bubble-sort

I had an argument with a friend about the real bubble sort of the following two algorithms, and about which one is better, no mention which one is mine, I just want to hear your answers on these two questions about those two algorithms (written in c++)

1-which one is the real bubble sort?
2-which one is better?

here are the two algorithms :

```
// Number one :
void BubbleSort(int Arr[], int size)
{   for (int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
        for (int j=i+1;j<size;j++)
            if (Arr[i]>Arr[j])
            {   int temp = Arr[i];
                Arr[i] = Arr[j];
                Arr[j] = temp;
}           }

// Number two : 
void BubbleSort(int Arr[], int size)
{   for (int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<size-1;j++)
            if (Arr[j]>Arr[j+1])
            {   int temp = Arr[j];
                Arr[j] = Arr[j+1];
                Arr[j+1] = temp;
}           }
```

Comment: It should be noted that bubble sort should never be used in any kind of production code, as it plainly sucks compared to other comparison based sorts like insertion sort e.g., which is as easy to implement but outperforms bubble sort in nearly (if not all) cases. I even go as far and say that bubble sort shouldn't be taught any more.

Comment: Python is down the hall, 2nd door to the right. Seriously: use C indentation; don't disguise it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Number Two is closer to the real one. All comparisons should be between adjacent elements.

But the real bubble sort would take a `while` loop instead of an outer `for` loop, and the `while` loop would execute again only if elements had to be swapped on the last pass, like this:

```
void BubbleSort(int Arr[], int size) 
{   
    bool swapped;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (int j=0;j<size-1;j++)
            if (Arr[j]>Arr[j+1]) {
                int temp = Arr[j];
                Arr[j] = Arr[j+1];
                Arr[j+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
    } while (swapped);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to re-initialise swapped to false after each pass, no ?

Answer (score 1):

The pseudocode for the nested loop bubble sort is:

```
procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items ) 
  n := length(A)-1
  for(i=0; i<= n; i++) 
     for(j=n; j>i; j--) 
        if A[j-1] > A[j] then
           swap (A[j-1], A[j])
        end if
     end for
  end for
end procedure
```

This means that the first is closest because the inner loop only iterates over elements after i. The second method you showed has an inner loop which iterates over all elements, even though elements before i have already been sorted, so there's no need to waste time on them.

That means the first method is also better.

Comment: But in his first method, he's comparing Arr[i] and Arr[j], not Arr[j-1] and Arr[j]

Answer (score 1):

The answer to question #2:  Neither is "better".  Both are O(n^2) sort algorithms (which are terrible).  Other than an introduction to sorting algorithms, Bubble Sort is useless.